# InputBox-driven Simple Summation in VBA

Tags: vba

I'm obviously a newb and I am trying to create a simple summation using values asked for in an InputBox.
What I am trying to do is request the values to sum using a simple question dialogue such as "Enter Next Value" and then end that dialogue and sum the numbers if the value entered is zero.

Comment: Can you please show an example of what you have already tried, and a more detailed example of what you expect the input/output to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that you are trying to have a dynamic amount of input boxes, so the user can decide how many number they want to sum.

```
Dim TotalNum As Variant
Dim Hits As Long
Dim SumNums As Variant
Dim EnteredNum As Double
TotalNum = InputBox("How Many Numbers Do You Want to Sum?")
If TotalNum = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
    For i = 1 To TotalNum
        EnteredNum = InputBox("Enter Number Here")
        SumNums = SumNums + EnteredNum
        Hits = Hits + 1
    Next i
MsgBox SumNums / Hits
```

I think this is what you are looking for but your question isn't 100% clear.

Comment: That is fantastic! I removed the "/Hits" from the msgbox to just show resulting summation, but this is perfect.

Comment: I also tweaked it a bit to show the numbers entered to sum and then clear that list when the vba is executed again.